# Sql Server 2008 - How to query for status of fulltext catalogs on all user databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have several databases in a Sql Server 2008 R2 instance. Some of those databases have a full-text enabled table. The name of the full-text table is equal for all databases, but the databases have different names and they are created on demand (I never know what databases exists and what does not).

The thing is: I need to query all catalogs in all databases to check if a population is done, but I have no idea how many databases I have (of course I know, but they are created on demand as I said). The script must query all databases and check if a population is done in a table (which the name I know because it never changes besides the name of the database that does change)

I have seen many people using things like:

```
sys.fulltext_catalogs
```

But it does not work if i am using the master database for example.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Here is more complete code with a cursor, a full list of databases (even those without catalogs), and the right catalog view name:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += ' UNION ALL 
    SELECT [name] = ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''', 
    catalog_name = name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI,
    is_importing
  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.fulltext_catalogs'
  FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4;

SET @sql = 'SELECT [database] = d.name, 
    s.catalog_name,
    s.is_importing
FROM sys.databases AS d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (' + STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, '') + ') AS s 
ON QUOTENAME(d.name) = s.name
WHERE d.database_id > 4;';

CREATE TABLE #temp(db SYSNAME, catalog_name NVARCHAR(255), is_importing BIT);

INSERT #temp EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DECLARE @db SYSNAME, @catalog_name NVARCHAR(255), @is_importing BIT;

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY
FOR SELECT db, catalog_name, is_importing FROM #temp;

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db, @catalog_name, @is_importing;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @catalog_name IS NULL
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'No catalogs for ' + @db;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @is_importing = 1
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Do something to ' + @db 
                + '(importing)';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT @db + ' is not importing.';
        END
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @db, @catalog_name, @is_importing;
END

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;

DROP TABLE #temp;
```

Comment: It does not work. Error message is "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'MyDataBase.full_text_catalogs'", where MyDataBase is the name of one of my many databases. Also, this way I am not able to see if the catalog is done indexing because it does not return a record set to me. I need to be able to manipulate the data returned by the query.

Comment: Sorry, it should be sys.fulltext_catalogs, I added an extra underscore. Anyway if a database doesn't come back in the list, doesn't that mean that there are no full text-catalogs?

Comment: Did you miss the `sys.` in the script?

Comment: Now it works, but how do i do to manipulate those results if this query is running with `exec`? I mean, I need to iterate over all results using a cursor, but `exec` does not allow me to.

Comment: Ok .. i figured out how to open a cursor using `exec`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This gives you a complete list of used catalogs.

```
CREATE TABLE #info (
  databasename VARCHAR(128)
, [Fulltext Catalog Name] VARCHAR(128));

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO #info

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use ? 
SELECT ''?''
     , name 
FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs;'

SELECT * FROM #info 


-- get rid of temp table 
DROP TABLE #info;
```